# How do you create multiple strokes on text in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to create text that looks like this in WPF:

[image: sample text]

Notice that it is yellow text, with a black stroke, then a yellow stroke, then another (very thin) black stroke. Now, I can create a *single* stroke with little difficult by following [How to: Create Outlined Text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745816(v=vs.110).aspx). Note that the properties not shown are all DP's of the containing control.

```
protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext drawingContext)
{
    // Draw the outline based on the properties that are set.
    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(Fill, 
                                new System.Windows.Media.Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness), 
                                _textGeometry);
}

/// <summary> 
/// Create the outline geometry based on the formatted text. 
/// </summary> 
public void CreateText()
{
   System.Windows.FontStyle fontStyle = FontStyles.Normal;
   FontWeight fontWeight = FontWeights.Medium;

   if (Bold == true) fontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;
   if (Italic == true) fontStyle = FontStyles.Italic;

   // Create the formatted text based on the properties set.
   FormattedText formattedText = new FormattedText(
      Text,
      CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-us"),
      FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
      new Typeface(
          Font,
          fontStyle,
          fontWeight,
          FontStretches.Normal),
      FontSize,
      System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black
    );

    // Build the geometry object that represents the text.
     _textGeometry = formattedText.BuildGeometry(new System.Windows.Point(0, 0));
}
```

So my question is, how do I take that and add another (or several other) stroke(s) to it?

Comment: What about adding multiple strokes over each other? Each time with a smaller thickness?

Comment: @codemonkey That could work... You are suggesting multiple `DrawGeometry` calls with the same fill but different sized strokes? I would prefer for the stroke to go outside the original text, but that might be a simple way to accomplish the effect.

Comment: I don't see why you haven't gone with codemonkey's solution.  What do you mean by "I would prefer for the stroke to go outside the original text"?  Doesn't it get rendered half inside, half outside?  If so, all you need to do to get the outermost outline is use a stroke width of two times the distance from the text geometry to the outside of the outermost outline.  Then you use similar math to produce all the other strokes, and finally do a fill with no stroke for the inside.

Comment: @adv12 Yes, I thought my method was an outside stroke, but discovered today that its actually a center stroke. His method would work fine (if not better than my other approach). If it was an answer, I would certainly upvote and probably accept.

Comment: Why not use a LinearGradientBrush?

Comment: @dodexahedron A LinearGradientBrush applies as if the *entire* geometry is the brush. What that ends up doing is not "evenly" applying the gradation, since how much of each color you see depends on where in the geometry you are. Also, you would have to use a RadialGradientBrush to get even close (Linear would look *way* off)

Comment: Bummer. Even when used on the stroke? (Note I have not tried yet - I'm writing it up now)

Comment: @dodexahedron Yes, even when used on the stroke. If you look on the example page, you can see that the brush used for the stroke is applied over the entire geometry, not just "wrapped around" the geometry in pieces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to combine the stroke geometry with the initial geometry, then stroke *that* for the second stroke.

Luckily, .NET proves [`Geometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615692(v=vs.110).aspx) for getting the stroke geometry. You can then use [`Geometry.Combine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607449%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to combine the two:

```
_combinedGeometry = Geometry.Combine(_textGeometry, 
        _textGeometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry(new Pen(Stroke, StrokeThickness * 2)), 
        GeometryCombineMode.Union, null);
```

Note the `StrokeThickness * 2`. You need this because WPF draws a *center* stroke, and without it, the second stroke will at least partially (if not fully) cover up the first one. Then draw as before, with `null` for Fill:

```
drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, 
        new System.Windows.Media.Pen(SecondaryStroke, SecondaryStrokeThickness), 
        _combinedGeometry);
```

You can repeat this for additional strokes, or use a collection with a loop.

**Warning**: `GetWidenedPathGeometry` will not always return a "perfect" stroke based on the font you are using, the size of the font, and the size of the stroke. You may have to play around with it a bit in order to not have any artifacts.

**Workaround for above**: If possible, increase the font size. It increases the distance between pieces of stroke, reducing the likelihood that the algorithm will "bridge" the two pieces, or create other artifacts.